# Screen flicker only on gray backgrounds

Tags: 7.0-nougat, screen, troubleshooting

I have a Sony z5 premium, and have had many problems with the screen flickering on gray backgrounds. It's fine on white colors, so it may be something software?

I am using android 7.0

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

this is hardware fault, check the LCD belt or the LCD